# Javac não é reconhecido como comando interno ou externo

Tags: java, windows, linha-de-comando

Estou tentando compilar uma classe em java via linha de comando (cmd), porém não consigo, o erro mostrado é:

> 'java não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lote.

Imagem do prompt com o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz a configuração das variáveis de ambiente da seguinte forma:

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

e

```
PATH:
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;
C:\Users\7\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;
C:\Users\7\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;
C:\Users\7\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;
C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\
```

Comment: Está tentando compilar pela linha de comando? coloque o comando que executou.

Comment: pelo cmd , já tentei mas não vai

Comment: Coloque o comando do cmd, oa código java está dentro de algum packge?

Comment: não está em nenhum package

Comment: Qual é o erro? Edite sua pergunta e adicione o erro, e se achar necessário, o código que você fez.

Comment: Nani boa tarde, o @rray pediu pra voce colocar na pergunta o comando e o codigo que tentou compilar, informe estes dados pra que seja possivel entender qual o problema e pra que seja possivel lhe ajudar :) Ate mais.

Comment: postei a imagem

Comment: Agora melhorou. Pelo jeito as variaveis de ambiente não foram configuradas corretamente ou o cmd que vc executou estava com as configurações antigas.

Comment: já configurei umas 4 vezes as variáveis de ambiente '-'

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o valor delas como texto, na imagem não da para ver o JAVA_HOME em PATH.

Comment: pronto, porem o path modificou a alteração sozinho '-'

Comment: No final do PATH, adicione isso: `;%JAVA_HOME%`, de ok e vá confirmando, feche todos os cmd, abre um novo cmd e rode `javac` ou `java --version`.

Comment: quando rodei javac não foi, e java --version apareceu a seguinte mensagem : error: could not to create java virtual machine

Comment: Veja essa possível [solução para este erro aqui](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-1761312/fix-create-java-virtual-machine-issue.html).

Comment: Voce instalou o JDK pra 32bits?

Answer (score 23):

1. Clique com o botão direito em "Meu Computador" e depois em
   propriedades.
2. Na aba "Avançado" clique em "Variáveis de Ambiente".
3. Em "Variáveis do Sistema" clique em "Nova...", vai abrir uma
   janelinha pra você...
4. Em "Nome da Variável" digite "JAVA_HOME"
5. No "Valor da Variável" digite o caminho onde você instalou o JDK ali
   de cima... no seu caso "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60". Pronto,
   OK...
6. Agora em "Variáveis de Usuário" procure uma variável chamada "PATH",
   caso não exista clique em "Nova...", senão clique em "Editar..."
7. Quem clicou em "Nova..." coloque como "Nome da Variável" o texto
   "PATH" e como seu valor o texto "%JAVA_HOME%\bin
8. Quem clicou em "Editar..." adicione no final do valor da variável o
   texto "**;** %JAVA_HOME%\bin"
9. Abra um novo prompt de comando e execute o javac

Comment: continua não compilando x.x

Comment: To com o mesmo problema, ja tentei reinstalar o java e recriar os caminhos, mas ele continua a apontar que java nao é um comando valido