# Mapa não aparece em aplicativo

Tags: android, google-maps

Estou adicionando uma função num app meu que vai mostrar locais específicos perto do usuário.

( [Segue o exemplo que me embasei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971717/mapactivity-query-for-nearest-hospital-restaurant-not-working) )

Segue print da tela na activity:

[image: Tela]

EDIT:

```
E/Google Maps Android API(21658): Authorization failure.  Please see the Google Console for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API(21658): In the Google Developer Console
E/Google Maps Android API(21658): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
E/Google Maps Android API(21658): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
E/Google Maps Android API(21658):   API Key: AIzaSyA********************************
E/Google Maps Android API(21658):   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 42:89:CD:56:4E:08:9A:67:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**;"NOME DO MEU PACOTE"
```

A chave tá criada, mas ocorre o erro acima

Também o ocorre um NullPointer:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
```

Eu nem alterei nada na classe.

Segue o trecho onde ocorre o erro:

Linha 72:

```
StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(sbMethod());
```

Linha 144:

```
    public StringBuilder sbMethod() throws SecurityException {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    mLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
```

Comment: Detalhe mais o seu problema, coloque partes do seu código.

Comment: Você gerou a chave da API?

Comment: Gerei, @ThiagoLuizDomacoski

Comment: Exibe algum erro no Console?

Comment: Adicionei os erros do console aqui, @ThiagoLuizDomacoski

Comment: Coloquei, @Taisbevalle

Comment: modo debug ou release?

Comment: tem uma parte que diz "Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.". Vc viu se no painel do google vc habilitou o maps?

Comment: @AndréVicente lá no console só encontrei Google Maps Android API, não encontrei o Google Maps V2.

Comment: Resolvi! Troquei a tag android:name="com.google.android.maps.V2.API_KEY" por android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY".

Answer (score 0):

Gerar uma chave da api:

http://andreleonis.blogspot.pt/2015/03/usando-o-google-maps-no-android-studio.html

No momento que está a fazer o get das coordenadas pode ainda não ter nenhuma em cache

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu sei que esta questão é antiga, mas vou compartilhar a solução da minha experiência com vocês, visto que pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Recentemente eu troquei de S.O e ocorreu o mesmo problema comigo, a solução foi instalar a última versão do Java através do link "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html" e configurar o JAVAC conforme "[Javac não é reconhecido como comando interno ou externo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86597/javac-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-reconhecido-como-comando-interno-ou-externo)".

Obrigado!